# Raspberry Pi Camera V2 - Can It Be Used For Capturing Objects in Motion?

Tags: camera-settings, raspberry-pi

I have a project where I was going to use a GoPro Hero3+ Black but due to the limitations of it I am looking at a Raspberry Pi Camera V2 (8MP) instead.

I know that people have successfully used the GoPro Hero3+ Black (with an aftermarket lens) to take photos of the ground from moving aircraft but can the Raspberry Pi Camera V2 be used to take similar photos with respect to motion blur?  I know the megapixels are less but can it handle the motion?  Is the rolling shutter of the Pi Camera too slow?  How would it compare to the GoPro Hero3+ Black?

Here are some specs I found: http://richshumaker.com/raspi/raspicamera.html.

Comment: Is your goal "photos of the ground from moving aircraft", or something else? What objects, what aircraft at what speed and height?

Comment: Aren't the specs you shared for the first Pi camera and not the one you are asking about? Do you have specs for the v2 camera?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I was finally able to find the shutter speed for the Pi Camera V2 and it is about 1/6000/sec.  So it should be plenty.

Answer (score 1):

There is a full module of python code that you can use to control everything from the exposure, to the color balance, shutter speeds and such. You can find all the goodies here:

http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/index.html

I have used the older camera (which had a far less profound sensor) in some pretty unusual ways. You can control a lot with it, but you will need to learn a bit of programming to get there.